# Can't rename project in Eclipse/STS

Tags: eclipse, list

I can't change maven projects name. I use Refactor > Rename option, I also changed project folder name in file system. Rename operatin is successful, but when I remove the project and then import, I end up with the old name again. 
I also changed :

```
<projectDescription>
    <name>newName</name>
```

in .project but with no success.

How can rename the project name for good?

Answer (score 1):

When you rename the project, make sure the name is also updated in the `pom.xml`, I think Eclipse m2e will adapt the Eclipse project name according to what's in the pom.